# Perl period vs comma operator

Tags: perl, conditional-operator, comma-operator

Why does

```
print "$str is " , ispalindrome($str) ? "" : " not" , " a palindrome\n"
```

print "madam is a palindrome", but

```
print "$str is " . ispalindrome($str) ? "" : " not" . " a palindrome\n"
```

prints ""?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The conditional operator (`? :`) has higher precedence than the comma, but lower than the period. Thus, the first line is parsed as:

```
print("$str is " , (ispalindrome($str) ? "" : " not"), " a palindrome\n")
```

while the second is parsed as:

```
print(("$str is " . ispalindrome($str)) ? "" : (" not" . " a palindrome\n"))
```